# For a projectile to cover maximum vertical distance in the least time, what will be the angle of projection?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

My first guess was 90° as there is no horizontal component for velocity when the angle is 90°. But I could not prove it mathematically (and also I'm not sure if it is really 90°).

Comment: Is the initial speed fixed?

Comment: did you mean time taken to reach the respective maximum height for each angle of projection?

Comment: @Walter ,yes it is fixed

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When neglecting air drag, the vertical and horizontal motions decouple and we have the equations
\begin{align}
\ddot{x} &= 0,\\
\ddot{y} &=-g.
\end{align}
The initial conditions (at $t=0$) are $x=x_0$, $y=y_0$, $\dot{x}=v_0\cos\alpha$, and $\dot{y}=v_0\sin\alpha$ with $v_0$ the initial speed and $\alpha$ the angle of projection.

This gives the solutions\begin{align}
\dot{x} &=v_0\cos\alpha     & x &=x_0 + v_0\cos\alpha \,t \\
\dot{y} &=v_0\sin\alpha-gt  & y &=y_0 + v_0\sin\alpha \,t-\tfrac{1}{2}gt^2.
\end{align}
The maximum of $y(t)$ w.r.t. $\alpha$ occurs at $\alpha=\pi/2=90^\circ$ for any time $t$.

For large $v_0$, however, air drag cannot be neglected and the above analysis is invalid.
Nonetheless, the maximum still occurs at $\alpha=\pi/2=90^\circ$, because only for this value all of the initial kinetic energy $\tfrac12mv_0^2$ is invested in vertical motion only and nothing wasted in horizontal motion (which wouldn't increase the vertical distance travelled).

Comment: Note though that $y$ is a function of $t$ **and** $\alpha$, so you really have to do a minimization of *both* terms, i.e. solve $\partial_\alpha y=0,\,\partial_ty=0$ simultaneously.